# How do you clean scorched wort off stainless steel?

Tags: cleaning, equipment

[image: scortching]

Kettles, mash tuns, infants, etc

Comment: I'll fix the image when I get to a real computer.

Comment: Was this scorch in a direct fired mash tun? I am planning on building one and want to avoid this scenario.

Comment: Yep, the wort under my screen got way too hot because my pick-up melted. See my blog: http://midnighthourbrewery.blogspot.com/2010/02/domestic-something-else.html

Comment: I tasted the beer, a pre-Prohibition lager, last week. I detected no hints of the scorching in aroma, appearance or flavor. Classic American pilsner is not a style that hides flaws and I am happy the burn did not come through.

Comment: @Dean-Manage to make any headway on the scorch?  I'm sure if barkeeper's didn't work, then the oven cleaner would :)

Comment: I hope you post an update when you finally get the thing cleaned up.

Comment: I had to grind it off with my angle grinder.

Comment: I tasted the beer, a pre-Prohibition lager, last week. I detected no hints of the scorching in aroma, appearance or flavor. Classic American pilsner is not a style that hides flaws and I am happy the burn did not come through.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's on stainless steel [Bar Keepers Friend](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000V706OC) will clean off just about anything.  I use this on my ss pots and pans and it works great (I try not to use it on mirror finished surfaces though).

You can find it at Bed Bath & Beyond, Walmart, the grocery store, just about anywhere.

**EDIT:** I also believe that Bar Keepers Friend is a glass cooktop cleaner, so it can def cut through some scorched on food/sauce/liquid.

Comment: This may have worked eventually. I left a paste of BKF on the burn for a few hours and a little came off.

Answer (score 2):

It's toxic as heck, but standard oven cleaner is your last stop.  My progression would be:

- One-Step/PBW
- Barkeeper's Friend
- Oven Cleaner (which you can thankfully use outside if it's not on your oven)

Comment: Didn't try oven cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

I think an angle grinder with an abrasive pad will do the trick. That method is somewhere between Barkeeper's Friend and oven cleaner.

Comment: The bottom of my tun is nice & shiney now.

Comment: Power tools + brewing.... nice.

Answer (score 1):

I use PBW (Powdered Brewery Wash) and that gets everything off that I've ever used it for including scorching.

Comment: Tried this one today without success.

Comment: Did you use hot water to mix with the PBW and let it soak overnight? That's always worked for me. Then you use a gentle scrub brush and everything comes off nicely.

Comment: I used hot water and a four hour soak. A tiny bit came off. Even with hard scrubbing the burns didn't loosen their grip.

Answer (score 1):

Try vinegar and baking soda. It works for pots and pans.

Comment: This did not work either.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try using the PBW as a scouring agent itself.  Soak the pot with warm PBW for twenty minutes.  Empty the kettle. Sprikle in some fresh PBW without adding additional water, and scrub with a green pad.

Comment: A good soak with PBW did not work.